# Clearing a table in corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk, lua-table

I'm having problems with clearing the data in a LUA table. I use the Scene plugin and as soon as the player advances to the next scene, then I'd like to reset the data in a table.

I use this function to create the game elements:

```
local function createGrips()
    local originX = 0
    local originY = height -75

    for i=0,numberGrips do
        r = math.random(3)
        local x = originX + math.random(width)
        local y = originY - math.random(2*height)
        grip[i] = display.newRect(allElements, x, y, gripSize[r].w, gripSize[r].h)
        grip[i].status = "active"
        grip[i].size = gripSize[r].s
        if (r == 1) then
            grip[i]:setFillColor(51,255,0)
        elseif (r == 2) then
            grip[i]:setFillColor(255,51,51)
        elseif (r == 3) then
            grip[i]:setFillColor(51,51,255)
        end
    end
end 

createGrips()
```

As I move to the next scene I have tried all these options to clear the table:

```
grip={}
```

or this one

```
for i=#grip,0, -1 do
    table.remove(grip,i)
end
```

but the result stays the same. The elements keep staying on the screen. The only thing that was working was grip=nil. But this then created an error, as soon as I returned to the function `createGrips()`.

What would be the best way to reset all the data? I'm using the `removeSelf()` function for all the characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are similar question like this in corona like i said from my previous answer if you want to recreate all the data and values in your storyboard you must remove your scene after you go to another scene or you can reset your values on scene:Enterscene() function so if you go back to your previous scene it will reset the values

Maybe this links can help you

- for removing and purdging scene
  http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/07/31/storyboard-scene-purging-vs-removal/
- and this for storyboard
  http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2011/11/14/introducing-the-storyboard-api/

Comment: It helped. I used storyboard.purgeScene() and it worked. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: well i'm glad that i help you with your problem. by the way you can vote up my answer